# Ruby matches wrong with special characters like "|"

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, match

**Code:**

```
arr = ["this is | a test","this is a second test","this must be a third test"]
res = ["this is | a test test test ","this is a second test test test","this must be a third test test test"]

result = Hash.new

arr.each do |c|
  res.each do |i|
    if (/#{c}/.match("#{i}" ))
      result["#{c}"] = i
    end
  end
end

puts result
```

**result:**

```
["this is | a test" => "this is a second test test test",
 "this is a second test" => "this is a second test test test",
 "this must be a third test" => "this must be a third test test test"]
```

**Problem:**

The first match is wrong, the last match for "this is | a test" is "this is a second test", I've seen that he first matches the first value and then this second value.
Inserting a break is not an option. How can I be sure that the match with "|" is exactly matched, so I can get the following result:

```
["this is | a test" => "this is | a test test test ",
 "this is a second test" => "this is a second test test test",
 "this must be a third test" => "this must be a third test test test"]
```

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Why not use Backslashes?

Comment: @c650 because the array's are dynamical, we never know if and when the "|" characters will be present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in regex, `x|y` has the special meaning of *"match either `x` or `y`"* in regex. Therefore,

```
this is | a test
```

will indeed match `"**this is **a second test test test"`

---

You can use [`Regex.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-escape):

```
/#{Regex.escape(c)}/
```

Comment: thank you for this solution, worked like a charm, solution:

if (/#{Regexp.escape(c)}/.match("#{i}" ))